# Uploading .mp3 and image file; Difference b/w the two

Tags: php, image, audio, file-upload

Here is my script.:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
 echo $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']/['name']/['error']/['type'];
 // i.e. echoing all the temproray file location; name error status and type of file.
}
?>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?> method="post" />
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="SOME_VALUE" />
<input type="file" name="upload" id="upload" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</body>
</html>
```

Now here are the issues; basically i want the users to upload music on the site; but when i tried testing this code using some .mp3 file then i got the following troubles.

1. any file that is of size more that 8MB (i guess) does not get into the `isset($_POST['submit'])`  condition of the code.. Dont know why.
2. Now when i upload the file of a smaller size then i get the following outputs

   tmp_name   : NOTHING
   name       : Name of file is shown
   error      : 1 (i.e. the file is not uploaded?? )
   type       : NOTHING

3 Now when i upload the .jpeg file  i get all the desired results. i.e.

```
tmp_name   : Windows/temp/ BLAH...
name       : name of file
error      : 0 (i.e. successful upload)
type       : jpeg
```

Why is this happening?

Also is there a better way to lat the user upload an audio file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should review your php.ini [settings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php).

Those settings would determine the maximum file size you can upload:

- [upload_max_filesize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize)
- [post_max_size](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php)
- [memory_limit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit)
- [max_execution_time](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time)

Comment: and what exactly will i be reviewing?

Comment: set `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` to about 20MB. And also review `max_execution_time` and `max_input_time` (set about 200 for the last two)